# Sitecore Goals - Retrieve assigned item goals programmatically

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have built an MVC form which then uses javascript to post request to an API controller. Along with this request I am passing an item ID.

I'm looking to retrieve all of the goals assigned to a Sitecore item so I can retrieve the Goal ID and fire the goal request off programmatically.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Goals assigned to an item are stored in the `__Tracking` field.

E.g. if you assign built in `Newsletter Signup` goal to an item, content of the tracking field will be:

```xml
<tracking><event id="{1779CC42-EF7A-4C58-BF19-FA85D30755C9}" name="Newsletter Signup" /></tracking>
```

where the `{1779CC42-EF7A-4C58-BF19-FA85D30755C9}` is the ID of the `Newsletter Signup` goal item.

You would need to parse the field to get the goal item ID.